# How to use old MS Sans Serif Font

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, fonts

I'm working on a program which draws text on a bitmap. I have to use the old [MS Sans Serif 72](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYJ58.png) font, because **I need a big pixelated font**.

I found this font in the `C:\Windows\Fonts` folder, but when I use code like this:

```
Font myFont("MS Sans Serif", 72F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
myGraphics.DrawString(string1, font, solidBrush, New PointF(100, 10))
```

then `myFont` is set to *Microsoft Sans Serif*, instead of *MS Sans Serif*. Why is Windows changing it to a TrueType font, and how could i use a `.fon` file?

Could you tell me how to use *MS Sans Serif*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET only supports use of TrueType fonts (*.ttf), to be compatible with GDI+.

Using raster fonts (*.fon) in .NET is difficult and requires using Interop to access GDI methods.
See [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/) for some examples on how this might work using [TextOut](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/TextOut.html).

A simpler option might be to try to render your text to a bitmap, then scale up the bitmap to create a pixelated effect, for example:

```
int width = 80;
int height = 80;

using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height))
{
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        var font = new Font("MS Sans Serif", 16, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
        graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;
        graphics.DrawString("012345", font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
    }

    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, ClientRectangle, 0, 0, width, height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

---

**Update**: added improvements from @HansPassant's comment.

Comment: Add graphics.TextRenderingHint to disable anti-aliasing.  And make the bitmap smaller so it has to be scaled up with InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.